# не получается скрыть/показать text в зависимости от radio на javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте

Не работает "показ/скрытие" поля текст. вообще задача такая: изначально ни одно радио выбрано быть не должно(!). И если это так то вывести сообщение пользователю, иначе если выбран первый радио, то поле текст остается скрытым, если выбран второй радио, то поле текст появляется, вот код формы:

```html
<div class="text_error_form"></div>
<div class="registration_form">
  <form method="post" onsubmit="return RegFormValid();">
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
    </p>
    <p class="user_type">
      <input type="radio" name="user" value="privato" />
      <input type="radio" name="user" value="giuridica" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="login" id="reglogin" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="regpass" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="iva" id="iva" style="display: none;" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="town" id="town" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="register_user" value="Reg" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Нужно, что бы когда выбран один radio, то блок `#iva` закрывался, а при клике на второй - открывался. Но если не выбран ни один radio, то пользователю выводится сообще, где написано, что он должен выбрать. На данный момент если ни выбран ни один радио пользователю не сообщается а должно. если кто-то считает нужным может оптимизировать скрипт

Comment: В смысле не советовать библиотеку, если у вас и так написано на JQuery?)

Comment: я бы рекомендовал сократить код до момента, пока не останется только проблемная часть. такое полотно вряд ли кому-то захочется анализировать. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: То есть Вам нужно создать полноценный компонент? Тогда это на фриланс биржи(!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё делается очень просто:

**JQuery** вариант:

```js
$('[name="register_user"]').click(function() {
  
  // Сама проверка
  if($('[name="user"]:checked').length){
    if($('[name="user"]:checked').val() == 'privato'){
      $('#iva').hide();
    }else{
      $('#iva').show();
    };
  }else{
    console.log('Вы не выбрали ничего!');
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text_error_form"></div>
<div class="registration_form">
  <form onsubmit="RegFormValid()">
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
    </p>
    <p class="user_type">
      <input type="radio" name="user" value="privato" />
      <input type="radio" name="user" value="giuridica" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="login" id="reglogin" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="regpass" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="iva" id="iva" style="display: none;" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="town" id="town" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="register_user" value="Reg" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JS** вариант:

```js
document.querySelector('[name="register_user"]').onclick = function() {
  
  // Сама проверка
  if(document.querySelectorAll('[name="user"]:checked').length){
    if(document.querySelector('[name="user"]:checked').value == 'privato'){
      document.querySelector('#iva').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
      document.querySelector('#iva').style.display = 'block';
    };
  }else{
    console.log('Вы не выбрали ничего!');
  };
  
};
```

```html
<div class="text_error_form"></div>
<div class="registration_form">
  <form onsubmit="RegFormValid()">
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
    </p>
    <p class="user_type">
      <input type="radio" name="user" value="privato" />
      <input type="radio" name="user" value="giuridica" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="login" id="reglogin" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="regpass" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="iva" id="iva" style="display: none;" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="town" id="town" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="register_user" value="Reg" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Сначала мы должны проверить нажат ли хотя бы на один radio. Если нет, то мы выводим сообщение, а если да, то переходим к следующей проверке.
Во втором мы проверяем, какой был отмечен, если первый, то мы скрываем `input`, а если второй, то показываем

Comment: спасибо Ваш ответ мне помог, помогите немного доработать js вариант: как правильно повесить событие onclic на radio а не на submit и когда отмечен radio == 'privato' то сразу идет отправка формы, однако этого не должно быть потому что ниже есть еще поля которые должны проверяться!

Comment: @privetsh, вам нужно сразу проверять radio? Если да, то можно использовать события `onchange` или `oninput` и от туда всё так же будет